# How to get SQLite to ignore the first 17 rows of .csv file?

Tags: sql, sqlite, csv

I'm brand new to using SQL and I'm not quite sure where to begin.  I have many .CSV files in a folder and I wanted to go about making a database in order to provide a way to search through the information stored in each .csv file. All of the files are identical in their parameters, meaning all of the files are set up the same way in terms of columns and rows. Due to the way everything is set up and how files are laid out identically, this should be easy to code in SQL.  Currently I am using SQLite in order to store and organize all of the data AFTER the first 17 rows of information  **Deleting the first 17 rows is also acceptable**.  I am familiar with Java and C++, but I'm not quite sure I understand how to skip or delete the first 17 rows in SQL, I also do not know how to code for this in SQLite.  I would think that this is a simple thing, but I can't find anything on how to achieve this, **skipping or deleting the first 17 rows of each .csv file**.  How would I go about telling SQLite to delete the first 17 rows?

Comment: What defines the *order* of the rows? E.g. the 17 earliest dates, 17 lowest IDs? - The order in the file is unrelated to the order in a table once its been imported ...

Comment: I believe you may want to look at the LIMIT function in mysql. it is similar to ROWNUM in oracle and TOP in MSSQL.   You should be able to LIMIT > 17 if this functions as ROWNUM does

Comment: delete from table where id < 17.. or just open the csvs and delete the first first rows before importing.. you said that was acceptable so why didn't you just do it? your question is not clear..

Comment: Are the first 17 rows in the same format as the data you want to keep?  If not, you may be be better off writing a program outside SQL to drop the 1st 17 rows of each file.  If they are the same, allow them all to import assign a row ID on import starting at 1 for each file and then delete the 1st 17 of each file's data set after the imports.  `Delete from table where RowID <=17`.  It's not always necessary to do everything in one step especially if a simpler solution involves 2-3 steps.

Comment: The reason I don't manually delete the first 17 rows is there are thousands of files created by a java program I made.    I just want SQLite to remove the first 17 rows(from the top) of any table I import into the database.  I may be importing tons of tiles at a time, so I need SQLite to remove 17 rows each time a table is imported

Comment: So, why not do this job on your java program and regenerate those files?!

Comment: because I don't know how to cut the 17 rows from the top.  It only cuts 17 rows off of the bottom